# HOW to decrypt a message using only a public key?

Tags: encryption, cryptography

Can I decrypt a message using only a public key?

I have just have 2 file  (message.enc , public.pem)

I've tried to decrypt the message.enc and i haven't the private key.

Comment: Wouldn't that defeat the purpose of allowing one key to be public?

Comment: Unfortunately you can't if the message is encrypted by the public key. That's how the asymmetric encryption is meant to work

Comment: what if the message incrypt bu privet kek ?

Answer (score 4):

No. That's what private and public keys are used for. The public key is usually used for **encryption** and the private key is required for **decryption**.